# How to make a comma-separated list of all the students (name + surname) who enrolled in the course

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need in the view show students Name + Surname through the comma.

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

and my view looks like, I know hpw to add a column, but I dont know how to show students Name + LastName

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Enrollment Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: plz post your view...

Comment: how you are trying to show ?

Comment: I was trying to write something like this:                </td>@string.Join(", ", item.LastName)</td>                           but I dont know what need to write in controller and how to show full name(FirstMidName + LastName)

Comment: Im sure somebody should know it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this

Controller:

```
public ViewResult Registrants() {
IList<CompetitionNames> names = new List<CompetitionNames>();
foreach (Competition comp in repository.Competitions) {
names.Add(new CompetitionNames {
EventName = comp.Name,
RegistrantNames = comp.Registrations.Select(e => e.Name).Distinct()
});
}
return View(names);
```

View:

```
@foreach (var comp in Model) {
<tr>
<td>@comp.EventName</td>
<td>@string.Join(", ", comp.RegistrantNames)</td>
<td>@comp.RegistrantNames.Count()</td>
</tr>
}
```

I saw this in Applied ASP.NET 4 in Context BOOK at page 685

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a partial class to show FirstName + Surname as Fullname... Not sure if this helps

```
    public partial class Student
{
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(" ", FirstMidName, LastName);
        }
    }

}
```